# CloudFlare - requests with empty HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP

Tags: security, xss, cloudflare

We have a website (with CloudFlare in front).

We are constantly getting scanned/checked for vulnerabilities and requests look like this:

```
2020-01-28 14:19:59  Content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
2020-01-28 14:19:59  Request content: <?=md5("phpunit")?>
2020-01-28 14:19:59  HTTP referer: 
2020-01-28 14:19:59  User agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36
2020-01-28 14:19:59  HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP: 
2020-01-28 14:19:59  HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY: 
2020-01-28 14:19:59  Query: path=vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php
2020-01-28 14:19:59  REMOTE_ADDR: 5.101.0.209
2020-01-28 14:19:59  REMOTE_HOST:
```

I have added address 5.101.0.209 to firewall in CloudFalre but requests are still coming through (somehow).

I have following questions

1. How can requests come via CloudFlare but variable
   HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP is empty?
2. How would you recommend to defend against such scanning?
3. Why CloudFlare firewall does not block such request, what could be the reasons?

Thanks.